# How to avoid plastic in aquaponics designs?

Tags: aquaponics, diy, building-materials

Ignoring the question of whether [aquaponics](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquaponics) is a sustainable process (which it may not be due to seemingly high energy input required for water movement and filtration).

Most [aquaponics](https://www.google.com/#q=diy+aquaponics) designs use plastic as a basic building block for every component.  Given [plastics are not sustainable materials](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/189/which-plastics-should-i-avoid-and-what-qualities-of-plastics-are-important-to-co), I'd like to avoid their use in "backyard" DIY projects.

What are some safe, renewable, water-resistant materials I could use instead of plastic in existing designs?

Are there "backyard" designs that avoid plastic materials and components?

Comment: Some related material might be found here — [How can I seal a pond without using a plastic pond liner?](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/169/117)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fun question.  I am not against plastics in my designs but lets see what we can do to get around this!

Wood?  I would think that a good hard wood with closely packed grain would be a great building block for grow beds and even the fish tank.  If you employed basic boat building skills and adhesives such as a resin you might be "sustainable".  You could use a trough design to move water from point A to point B...also achievable with wooden planks.

To get around the use of pumps you would probably need to employ something like a paddle wheels next to a flowing stream to carry water from a low point to a high point.  From there I think gravity could be employed.

As far as some form of ebb and flow system you would need to get tricky with your siphon.  Perhaps a loop siphon would be easier to achieve with natural pieces.  Perhaps cured animal gut could be dried in a loop siphon form.  But then again using bamboo to fashion a bell siphon might work pretty well.

Comment: A pretty normal approach to a pump is a small windmill attached to an archimedes screw- you'll see them all over the canals in the Netherlands. You can use gravity return through wood planks (wood does ok with moving water for a while, calm water can be very hard on it without proper maintenance).